# Universal Windows Platform webView override NavigationStarting

Tags: c#, android, webview, win-universal-app

I am developing a simple `UWP` page with a `web view`. I would like to do the following: if a external link is clicked I open the default brower, but if it is not a external link I want to navigate in my `web view` and add some extra headers. For this I have overrided the event WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs, this is my code:

```
 private async void WebView_Navigation_Starting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        args.Cancel = true;

        // external URL
        if (isExternalUrl(args.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
        {
            //cancel load
            args.Cancel = true;
            //launch default browser
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(args.Uri);

            progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
           HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, args.Uri);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> header in additionalHeaders) { 
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(header);
            }
            webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);  
        }

            progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

In the `Android` version it is done like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
    if (isExternalUrl(url)) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }

    tvError.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    setAdditionalHeaders();
    view.loadUrl(url, additionalHeaders);

    return true;
}
```

But I get a StackOverflow exception in this line `webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage)`. Does someone know what is wrong here?

**EDIT**

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="windows_phone.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="20"
Foreground="#FF000000">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <WebView 
            x:Name="webView" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // webView //
        webView.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.ScriptNotify += webView_ScriptNotify;
        webView.Source = new Uri(GetUrl("/"));
        webView.NavigationStarting += WebView_Navigation_Starting;
        webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_Navigated;
        webView.Loaded += WebView_Loaded;
        webView.LoadCompleted += WebView_LoadCompleted;
        webView.NavigationFailed += Web_View_Navigation_Failed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling this  webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage, when its already started navigating? You should remove that method. If its not External link you dont have to do anything. Or you have to do  args.Cancel = true; before you call that method

Comment: Ok, you are right, it is removed but  when a click a internal link the app does not do anything, I mean I cant navigate in the webview.

Comment: Can you post the xaml with internal link?it would be helpful to solve

Comment: I have already edited my question.

Comment: I am such a idiot, I did realized that I wrote `args.Cancel = true` in the second line of the method, so.. of course.. the navigation is canceled, sorry for wasting your time and thanks anyway!

Comment: Check my answer you can add the headers and call your previous method without exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call  webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage method Navigation_Starting event will be triggered again. So keep a boolean variable and make it false before you call the method.

```
     bool done = false;
            private void WebView_Navigation_Starting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
            {
 progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        args.Cancel = true;

        // external URL
        if (isExternalUrl(args.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
        {
            //cancel load
            args.Cancel = true;
            //launch default browser
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(args.Uri);

            progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
                if (!done)
                {
                    done = true;
                    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, args.Uri);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> header in additionalHeaders)
                    {
                       httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(header);
                    }
                    webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);

                }
         }
}
```